# Where should I ask nginx configuration questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm not sure if those questions belong on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour), [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), or perhaps [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)?

For example, where should one ask the following?

> Should $args be used with try_files? Like: 
> `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Comment: @gnat Since such questions should go on Server Fault or Pro Webmasters and that page makes no mention of either, I'd say no.

Comment: @RyanM agree (retracted my vote)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions about Nginx configuration are generally best asked on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), whose [on-topic subjects](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) include "managing the hardware or software of servers, workstations, storage or networks." It has a [thriving [nginx] tag](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/nginx) with over 15,000 questions, many of which are about configuring it.

The question would also be on topic at [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), which [notes that](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) "questions about web server configuration (e.g., URL rewriting, SSL, virtual hosting, running scripts, password protection, status errors, etc...)... are considered on-topic here."

As always, make sure it's clear exactly what you're asking—merely asking whether you *should* do something may be construed as opinion-based.  Explain what you're trying to do, and what exactly your concerns are about the approach you're considering.